# Hydrogenation of pent-4-en-2-one

Tags: organic-reduction

If one equivalent of $\ce{H2}/\ce{Pt}$ is made to react with one equivalent of pent-4-en-2-one, what will be the product formed?

Comment: Generally the double bond goes, but it depends on the catalyst system used.

Comment: Is there a reason to say so?

Comment: For your information, actually C=C is stronger than C=O bond with bond strengths 680 & 500 KJ/mol respectively.

Comment: @Neon Prince I have edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified the full reaction conditions - temperature and pressure can make a considerable difference - however this quote from Chemistry Libre Texts  [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Basic_Principles_of_Organic_Chemistry_(Roberts_and_Caserio)/16%3A_Carbonyl_Compounds_I-_Aldehydes_and_Ketones._Addition_Reactions_of_the_Carbonyl_Group/16.06%3A_Catalytic_Hydrogenation) (in turn quoting Basic Principles of Organic Chemistry by Roberts & Caserio) gives us a clear indication of the relative ease of hydrogenation of ketones vs double bonds.

> Hydrogenation of aldehyde and ketone carbonyl groups is much slower than of carbon-carbon double bonds so more strenuous conditions are required. This is not surprising, because hydrogenation of carbonyl groups is calculated to be less exothermic than that of carbon-carbon double bonds....It follows that it is generally difficult to reduce a carbonyl group in the presence of a carbon-carbon double bond by hydrogenation without also saturating the double bond. Other reducing agents are more selective: